# Verb form in secondary clause when main clause uses an auxiliary

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, clauses

> Microwave heating can offer rapid and homogeneous heating and thus **avoids**
>   unwanted temperature gradients.

I'm confused about whether to use a singular or plural verb in the secondary clause of a sentence where the main clause has an auxiliary verb (in this case, *can*).

Further, how would the meaning of the sentence change if *avoids* was replaced with *avoid*?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'microwave' as the wave in the radiation spectre, I'd recommend you such phrase as 'microwave radiation.'  A listener could disambiguate the meaning of the whole sentence after such slight change. This change makes it necessary to transform the sentence into a kind as follows: Microwave radiation produces rapid and homogeneous heating in the oven and thus eliminates a possibility of unwanted temperature gradients.

If you mean 'microwave' as a microwave oven, I'd recommend such syntax as follows: Heating is rapid and homogeneous in a microwave that eliminates a possibility of unwanted temperature gradients.

If we do not resort to these changes, then the sentence is pragmatically vague. That is, it is completely not clear where it is pronounced: either at the school of chefs, or at some kind of physics exam. This uncertainty also causes the questions you asked about the syntax in your example, because people of a certain profession use usually the contexts and specific grammatical constructions inherent in this profession.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the first clause is the subject of the second clause connected by **and**.  The verb in each of the clauses must agree in number with the number of the subject.

To make the subject clearer, you can use a pronoun:

... and thus *it* ....

If you wish to restate the *capability*:

... and thus *can* avoid...

or

... and thus it can avoid...

You could switch the subject to **uniform heating** with a relative clause, and in so doing you would avoid the tautology (i.e. homogeneous heating = no temperature gradients):

> Microwave heating can offer rapid, *homogeneous heating, which*
>   prevents unwanted temperature gradients.

or you can express the causal relationship:

> Microwave heating can offer rapid, homogeneous heating, *thereby*
>   preventing unwanted temperature gradients.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening above is something similar to this:

> After recovering I can walk and therefore go to the store.

*Go* is "borrowing" *walk's* subject, and it's also borrowing *walk's* modal.

> After recovering I can walk and therefore [I can] go to the store.

The verb still has to agree with the subject even if it's "borrowed" and implied or elided.

The subject of *offer* in your example is *microwave heating*, and it's singular, so you have to use the third-person singular form *avoids*.  *Avoid* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Suppose,  if the word "thus" is absent, then i should modify the verb, am i correct?

Comment: Nope.  The subject of that second verb is still the same even without *thus*.

Answer (score 0):

The question hits upon a particular kind of redundancy.  When does microwave heat **not** offer “instantaneous and homogeneous heating?  Never!  That is what it does (strictly, one could quibble about whether the heating is strictly ‘homogeneous’.).  It **offers** those things to anyone thinking of buying such a heater.

So there is a crude *stylistic* fault, which we might call all sorts of thing: *unnecessary qualification* (as in a cricket commentator’s: “if the bowler’s first ball had hit the wicket, the batsman would **almost certainly** have been out.”).  But there is no grammatical error.